# '$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop version' works fine but 'hadoop version' doesnt work

Tags: java

I have installed hadoop 3.1.0 version and set env variables. When i run $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop version, it is shown that i installed but running hadoop version is not able to find the hadoop command (within hadoop user) 
My environment variables are like below:

```
#HADOOP VARIABLES START
export HADOOP_HOME=$HOME/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HOME/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HOME/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/usr/local/hadoop
#HADOOP VARIABLES END

echo $HADOOP_HOME
/usr/local/hadoop

echo $HOME 
/home/hduser



echo $PATH

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games


$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop version

Hadoop 3.1.0
Source code repository https://github.com/apache/hadoop -r 16b70619a24cdcf5d3b0fcf4b58ca77238ccbe6d
Compiled by centos on 2018-03-30T00:00Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 14182d20c972b3e2105580a1ad6990
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.0.jar
```

Seems like my global path is not working properly. I may miss something, i was trying to figure it out for hours, but nothing works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `echo $PATH` result, looks like hadoop path is not added to your `PATH`.

Where did you write your export statements? Try adding them to `~/.bashrc` and starting a new terminal.

Comment: I already added bashrc content and export statements in the question. It includes adding hadoop to PATH, could you please have a closer look at it? I opened another terminal and now the echo $PATH shows : /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/hduser/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/home/hduser/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/home/hduser/usr/local/hadoop
still hadoop is not a command though

Comment: trying hadoop version command on a new terminal and removing $HOME in front of the path solved the problem